# app:layout_collapseMode="pin" Not working

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a layout like following

[image]

I want the sticky header to stick to the top when recyclerview scrolls. Below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:elevation="1dp">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/food_disc_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_curve"
                android:paddingBottom="22dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@color/teal_700"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="Collapsable Text"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/masthead_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sticky Header"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But when scrolling the sticky header part also collapses.
[image]

If I move the sticky text out of collapsingToolBar then it would work. But the positioning matters. It should be

--Collapsible Text

--Sticky Text

--Frame Layout

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the scrollFlags from this

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/food_disc_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
```

to this

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/food_disc_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```